# Excel formula to check if there are duplicates of combinations of cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am working in Excel on a network that won't let me change the protection/shared status of a spreadsheet, and it just won't let me concatenate adjacent cells from two columns. I think it's a network issue and I don't understand it, but I have tried lots of ways of doing it and nothing has worked.

Besides that issue there should be a general formula for finding duplicates across two columns - so if I have a surname column and forename column, I can find people who have the same surname and forename like this:

```
Surname   Forename   Duplicate Y/N
Kirk      James         Y
Janeway   Katherine     N
Kirk      James         Y
```

Is there a way to do this without concatenating Surname and Forename columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this formula in your `C` column, which will show you the number of duplicate occurrences:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,B2)
```

And then in `D`:

```
=IF(C1 > 1,"Y","N")
```

---

Or, In 1 formula in `C` column:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,B2) > 1,"Y","N")
```

**Output:**

```
Surname   Forename    Duplicate Y/N
---------------------------------------------------
Kirk      James       Y
Janeway   Katherine   N
Kirk      James       Y
```

Comment: you can do it in one column with `=IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,A:A,B:B,B:B)>1,"Y","N")`